# Unique Number Generation Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, uniqueidentifier

I need to generate unique numbers for my Java application meeting the below requirements -

1. 9 digit hexadecimal
2. About 600,000 numbers to be generated everyday
3. The numbers must remain unique for a minimum period of 7 days; not a problem if they repeat beyond 7 days period.
4. During peak loads, about 800 unique numbers need to be generated every second for about 15 seconds.

Unsuccessful solution -

```
    public static String getUniqueId() {
        String uniqueTime = Long.toHexString(System.nanoTime());
        String uniqueId = uniqueTime.substring(uniqueTime.length() - 9);

        return uniqueId;
    }
```

A 12 digit hexadecimal number is generated by using the nanoTime. I truncate the 3 left characters. nanoTime helps is handling the peak load.

I believe this is not correct and it may result in duplicates.

Can anyone provide a good quick algorithm please?

Comment: Some math: 16^9/600000/365=313 years. Why not a simple counter?

Comment: What makes you think your solution may result in duplicates?

Comment: You should avoid using `System.nanoTime()`: http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.it/2012/02/what-is-behind-systemnanotime.html https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks

Answer (score 3):

If only one thread is used to generate the numbers:

```
long nextId = counter % MAX_VALUE;
counter++;
return convertToHex(nextId);
```

If multiple threads:

```
long nextId = atomicLongCounter.getAndIncrement() % MAX_VALUE;
return convertToHex(nextId);
```

Note: given @Gumbo's computation, it would need 313 years to reach the max value, so you can even drop the modulo.

Answer (score 2):

How about just using a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Definition)? They're incredibly useful in situations like this. [Java implementations available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html).

Comment: In principle, I would agree. Just that the poster may have a reason for specifically wanting 9-digit hex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: encryption.  Since encryption is reversible, you can guarantee that if the inputs are unique than the outputs are unique.  Use a 36 bit block cypher (36 bits = 9 hex digits) and encrypt the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

You can pre-generate as many as you want in advance during the slack times and store them.

Most of the common block cyphers aren't 36 bit (DES is 64 bit) but [Hasty Pudding Cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_Pudding_cipher) has a 36 bit variant or else you can use a fast stream cypher like RC4 or one of the [eSTREAM](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/) cyphers.

ETA: Stream cyphers will need rekeying for each number and so will probably be too slow for your purpose.  Rekeying also impacts uniqueness, since uniqueness is only guaranteed while using the same key.

Comment: Note that the standard SecureRandom class effectively does this, so you don't need to re-invent the wheel. You don't need to do any fancy pre-generation of numbers: a pre-generated instance of SecureRandom will generate thousands and thousands of numbers per second at the moment you need them. However, it isn't true that you guarantee that the outputs are unique once you add the condition of each number being 9 hex digits. Taking a random number in this range will mean duplicates are rare, but not impossible and you need to check for them and generate a new number when they occur.

Comment: For example, generating random 9 digit numbers with SecureRandom will give you in the order of 100 duplicates per week for the volume mentioned: trivial to detect the duplicates and generate a new number in each case, but you do need to check for them.

Comment: I am _not_ suggesting using a RNG.  Encryption will guarantee uniqueness for unique inputs, otherwise the encryption would not be reversible.

Comment: I think you misunderstand slightly: encryption guarantees reversibility for the *combination* of <ciphertext, key>. It doesn't guarantee a unique mapping of plaintext>ciphertext per se. So in your stream cipher, for example, there are different internal states of the cipher that could mean two different input numbers 'accidentally' end up with the same output. But on decryption, these are again differentiated by the internal state of the cipher at each relevant point.

Comment: You are right, a stream cypher would need to be rekeyed.  That probably makes a stream cypher too slow, as well as the keying issue.  I have edited my answer.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: N.B. You could still use a stream cipher-- it's not a bad idea per se-- it's just you need to take into account the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

-Another possibility for concurrent number generation

you could have up to 10 separate threads/processes/machines generating numbers guaranteed not to clash.

Just use a sequential counter to generate an integer

```
start one of them at 0, use increments of 10
start the next at 1, increments of 10
start the next at 2, increments of 10
```

even if one of the above ended up taking the full load, it can go 7 days without overflowing 9 digits because you have about 100 million in the sequence before 9 digits isnt enough, and you only generate 1 mil per day.

nice thing here is the threads/processes/machines are [shared nothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_nothing_architecture).

btw- you could do this directly in base 16 - just use increments of 16 instead of 10. Or base 5, increments of 5 etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the numbers to "look random", then you could just use a counter as others have suggested.

I'm guessing the reason you're looking for something complicated is because you want the numbers to "look random". In which case you could do the following:

- use an instance of SecureRandom to allocate your numbers
- keep in memory a map of "currently allocated" numbers mapped to their time of allocation (I think 600K numbers with this data stored in a ConcurrentHashMap will be in the order of a few tens of megabytes of data, so not a big deal by today's standards)
- each time you need to allocate a new number, just generate 9 random hex digits via your instance of SecureRandom (asking it to fill an array with 5 random bytes then discarding 4 of the bits will give you 9 hex digits' worth of random data)
- check if your new number is already in the map of allocated numbers. If so, just loop round and generate a new number until you get a unique one-- in reality, this will only happen 100 or so times per week for the volume you mention, so will have no performance impact though you do need to account for it;
- periodically, scan through your map of allocated numbers and purge ones that have been allocated for more than 7 days so that they can be re-used.

For a real-life application, you would also need to think about persistence: each time a number is allocated, you would need to persist it to a database before returning it to the client, so that the state can be recovered if your server crashes. Similarly, your purge operation would remove allocations from the database before removing from the in-memory map.

Answer (score 0):

Partly for amusement, allow me to also suggest another possibility from the specification you give. You could also find a pseudo-random number generation algorithm that, starting with a known seed, produces no duplicates in practice for the quantity of numbers that you need to generate per week.

For example, the following, based on an [XORShift generator](http://javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/xorshift.shtml), will produce 600000*7 random 9-digit numbers with no duplicates:

```
        long seed = 1;
        for (long i = 1; i <= 600000*7; i++) {
            long x = seed++;
            for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
                x ^= (x << 21);
                x ^= (x >>> 35);
                x ^= (x << 4);
            }
          x &= 0xfffffffffL;

          // "x" is now the next unique, random-looking number in the sequence
        }
```

The advantage of this method is that you need no storage other than the counter to determine which numbers have been generated so far.

The distadvantage is that each week, you start again with precisely the same sequence. And of course, if you suddenly need to increase your volume of allocated numbers, you may then need to find another sequence.

Anyway, I thought I'd throw it into the mix in case it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

`AtomicLong.incrementAndGet()` should do the trick.

If you need to persist it between JVM instances, you may want to allocate a range, store the max of that range in a database or other transactional store, and make sure to request a new range when you get close to the max in the `AtomicLong` (plus appropriate locking to ensure you don't go past that range.

But if you just need a unique number within one run, `AtomicLong.incrementAndGet` is simple and guaranteed to be unique until it wraps to -1, whicch 1) won't happen in your lifetime and 2) is easy to check for.